# Projecting a 3D point to a 2D point makes things get inverted

Tags: javascript, 3d, projection, html5-canvas

It seems everything in back of the camera get's inverted back or something:
[image: current screenshot]

This is the original model:
[image: original model]

So the camera is in the right opening of the "frame".

Here's the depth calculation (I think the problem is here):

```
function 3dto2d(x, y, z) {
    var scale = cameradistance / (cameradistance - z);
    return {
        'x' : x * scale,
        'y' : y * scale
    };
}
```

Does someone know this problem?

**EDIT: I have the answer here:**

```
function 3dto2d(x, y, z) {
    var scale = cameradistance / (cameradistance - (z >= cameradistance ? cameradistance - 1 : z));
    return {
        'x' : x * scale,
        'y' : y * scale
    };
}
```

Comment: Without much more detail we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Wat do you want? There's not much more useful I think.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't give us any code.

Comment: Wel we would need relevant code :)

Comment: -1: unknown engine, unknown libraries, unknown setup, no code, etc

Comment: Well when I said "no code", I meant, "no relevant code". Thanks for the random snippet of unrelated code though.

Comment: There's some code there, I don't know where the problem is. That's what I'm asking ;)

Comment: I think when the vertice gets in the back of the point where the camera is. The Z-cords get inverted? Come on there's not much more relevant information to tell.

Comment: @Stijntjhe: you've told us nothing. We've got two jpegs and a very very small snippet of javascript that we're supposed to base our diagnosis on. Seriously? I'm a programmer, not a magician.

Comment: You guys don't understand the question I guess. I'm asking if someone is similar with problems like this. Not if you want to search for something in the code.

Comment: You're assuming that the problem is in the code you posted? But what if you're wrong about that? What if it's just a stupid error in the code you _didn't_ post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This also happened to me when points have a `z <= 0`, because then the projection formulas are invalid. Just don't rotate your object in such a way that points get `z <= 0`.

It's inverted because the formula `y = 1 / x` is point symmetric around the origin. So for `x <= 0` then `y` becomes `-y`. E.g., `1 / 2 = 1 / 2`, but  `1 / -2 = - 1 / 2`.

To come to the point, I'd say you'd be best off altering your engine so as to map values `z <= 0` to `z = 1` (or something smaller). Though this is a cheap trick, of course. There are probably more meaningful techniques for this.

Comment: There's the answer, it's dissapointing people want to close the question. There's noting wrong about it.

Comment: @Stijntjhe: Als je het probleem niet weet is het soms moeilijk de relevante code te posten :)